# Web service needs to be called every 5 minutes. which is the efficient way to do this?

Tags: wcf, iis

I have WCF service which is hosted in the IIS 7 or IIS 8 server. The mentioned service should be called every 5 minutes. Which is the efficent way to do this. i have considered jquery/ajax call. what should be considered for doing this. And periodically send a request to IIS make any touble?. please anyone help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using Gooooooooogle for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer for my own question. I have created the windows service and added my WCF webservice as service reference and implemented timer for calling the service method.
Now working fine.